# Birthday Icon on the Curren Date

Tags: javascript, css

I have a Calendar which show the birthday reminder for our users , everything is going good but now I want that my calendar will show a small pic on a current date if there is anyone's birthday in that day . Only in a current day . Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think a good starting point would be using JS Link on your calendar's view. You should refer the following article to get some idea on how to use JSLink with SharePoint's list views, if you don't know much about it: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Based on this, you might need to find appropriate templates that you need to override for calendar view.